# Is there a way to group python3 dependencies into one folder to reduce redundancy while projects reside in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have noticed that the requirements.txt in some projects I have call for the same dependency,
So my question is if I was to sort each project in a similar tree as a Linux ISO
"/pool/Listed_Alphabet/A/Assorted_Project/Dependencies.txt"
"/pool/Listed_Alphabet/D/Dependencies/Dependency_files.py"

While running a project from within the project folder works, as each dependency is in the same folder, but if I have multiple projects that call for the same dependency, is there a way to only have one instance of the dependency and have each project call it as needed?

I am not familiar with the python structure, I have considered changing the path to the dependency
but that would become more tedious if the list of projects becomes bigger to manually edit every dependency.txt file especially if there are multiple dependencies listed in each file.
So I'm asking if there is an easier way to reduce redundancy and maintain operability

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you want tips. I'm out of my depth here, but FWIW I'm not understanding your project structure. You might want to [edit] and add more details.

Comment: It sounds like you're not aware that Python comes with virtual environment management. You should probably read up on that.